# how to properly reference a local repo with package.json / HOWTO Build ES Module Format for Vue Library using Vue CLI

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-cli, esmodules

I should make it clear that I'm using `vite` + `bun` not vue-cli, NPM or yarn.

The specific package is `vue-command`
https://github.com/ndabAP/vue-command

When run the build command that is used in the library's GitHub workflow (yarn build:lib), it seems to only produce CommonJS (common.js) and UMD (umd.js) formats, but not ES Module format.

````
yarn build:lib
yarn run v1.22.18
$ vue-cli-service build --target lib --name vue-command ./src/library.js

⠹  Building for production as library (commonjs,umd,umd-min)...```

⠹  Building for production as library (commonjs,umd,umd-min)...
````

However, there's no ES Module format file (typically with .esm.js or .mjs extension).

I can't figure out how the package on npmjs works at all are there build commands I'm missing?

When I look at the library on npmjs, it seems to be working fine, which makes me wonder if there are additional build commands or configurations that I'm missing to generate an ES Module format.

Questions:

- How can I configure Vue CLI to build the vue-command library in ES Module format?
- Is there a specific part of the Vue CLI configuration that I should modify to achieve this?
- Are there any additional steps or commands that I need to run to generate .esm.js or .mjs files?

Any help or guidance on how to correctly build this Vue library in ES Module format would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forked the original repo & no other changes (you can fork it).  
When I use the project from npmjs then I'm able to import the module. 
`import VueCommand from "vue-command";`
will works when I do `bun add vue-command` 
BUT if I do `bun add ../vue-command`  (the path to the local clone, where I've run `yarn build:lib`) then it I get 

`SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/home/user/path/vue-command/dist/vue-command.common.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at CommandLineInterface.vue:5:8)`

Comment: I'm not sure where in my process/workflow I've taken a wrong turn. 
https://github.com/ndabAP/vue-command/issues/520

Comment: I think `bun add vue-command` converts the commonjs to esm for vite (from npmjs.org), but when I reference the local repo on my hard drive it does not.

Comment: Also found the #bun channel in Vite Land discord 
https://discord.com/channels/804011606160703521/1065456580713267200/1186614802831904828